# Linux C++: Accessing network statistics

Tags: c++, linux, networking, network-programming

I am developing a network statistic program in C++ for Linux.

I would like to access some statistical information about the current network connection.

E.g.:

- packet loss,
- bytes transferred (upload and download),
- current network load (upload and download),

**Any idea how to access this kind of information?**

---

so, i have been trying to accomplish my objective using de /proc, we can find alot of information, but there is some missing information i need. I am thinking in developing a simple C++ promiscuous application, using LibPcap, that captures the network traffic i need and starts taking the metrics i want.

The Con is that i think this is going to be CPU intensive, at least more then needed ...
Any thoughts about this ?

Comment: Do keep in mind that systems don't usually have a single "current" network connection. You'll also have to come up with some definition of "current network connection" so you know what interface you actually want to look at

Answer (score 5):

All this information are spread into `/proc/net` files (updated by kernel). The most important file is `/proc/net/netstat`. Into to `/proc/net/dev` there are device statistics. You could open and parse.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of information is available from the "files" in `/proc/net`.

`/proc/net/netstat` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is possible to retrieve statistics information programmatically through the [rtnetlink interface](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html). See e.g. [this mail for examples](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/libnl/2011-February/000200.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can access Network statistics trough `/sys/class/net/NAME_OF_DEVICE/statistics`.